# XML Comments for route parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, api-versioning

I am implementing a Web API project that will use the standard HelpPages area for documentation. I am using attribute routing and implemented ApiVersioning in my project. I've got most of my methods and models documented, however I am trying to figure out how to document the API version route parameter. Here is a example of my Controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// Controller for the License api.
/// </summary>
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/license")]
public class LicenseController : ApiController
{
    #region Software License Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Software License.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The parameters for the license.</param>
    /// <returns>The newly created Activation and Emergency Ids.</returns>        
    [Route("software")]
    [HttpPost]
    public LicenseCreateResponse CreateSoftwareLicense([FromBody] CreateSoftwareLicenseRequest value)
    {
       // License creation code
    }
```

After configuring the HelpArea and running the project, I get the following help info:

[image]

There is a description available for the version parameter, however I don't know how to document it. It's not part of the route as far as the method is concerned, so trying `<param name="version">...` is fruitless.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution might work, but it doesn't need to be that difficult. Out of curiosity are you using the official [API Explorer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning.ApiExplorer/) package for API versioning? It would appear not. The **IApiExplorer** implementation it provides documents the API version parameter for you, including a description.

Should you want to change the default description text provided out-of-the-box, you can easily do so in the API Explorer options like so:

```
configuration.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
    options => options.DefaultApiVersionParameterDescription = "The version" )
```

*Help Pages* have seemingly gone out of style in favor of Swagger/Swashbuckle, but the API Versioning API explorer should work seamlessly with it. If there are gaps or other pain points, I'd definitely be interested in hearing about them.

Answer (score 1):

URI Parameters section on action help page is intended for description of action parameters that are bind from the URI query string (e.g. `...?SomeParam=SomeValue`). In your case `version` is just a part of URI path that is not related to action parameters. So having it described in URI Parameters section could be confusing. That's why I propose to remove it from this section and (if required) put description for `version` template to some other section of help page.

To achieve this you should:

1. Remove `version` from URI Parameters list.
   This step is not trivial because `version` from route template is recognized by `ApiExplorer` as action parameter. Suppressing it will require modification of generated code that fills a model for API help page (`HelpPageApiModel`). This code resides in `HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.GenerateUriParameters()` method. Find the following lines:

   ```
   Debug.Assert(parameterDescriptor == null);
   // If parameterDescriptor is null, this is an undeclared route parameter which only occurs
   // when source is FromUri. Ignored in request model and among resource parameters but listed
   // as a simple string here.
   ModelDescription modelDescription = modelGenerator.GetOrCreateModelDescription(typeof(string));
   AddParameterDescription(apiModel, apiParameter, modelDescription);
   ```

   and add condition for `version` parameter:

   ```
   Debug.Assert(parameterDescriptor == null);

   if (apiParameter.Documentation == null && String.Equals(apiParameter.Name, "version", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
   {
       continue;
   }

   // If parameterDescriptor is null, this is an undeclared route parameter which only occurs
   // when source is FromUri. Ignored in request model and among resource parameters but listed
   // as a simple string here.
   ModelDescription modelDescription = modelGenerator.GetOrCreateModelDescription(typeof(string));
   AddParameterDescription(apiModel, apiParameter, modelDescription);
   ```

   Now you'll get the following help page:

   [image]
2. Add specific section for version URI template:

   Open view file `Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\HelpPageApiModel.cshtml` and add version section that you want. For example:

   ```
   ...

   <h2>Request Information</h2>

   <h3>Version info</h3>
   Put some info about version here.

   <h3>URI Parameters</h3>
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UriParameters, "Parameters")

   ...
   ```

   Such view will give you:

   [image]

If however you want to see version description in URI Parameters section, you could return to `HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.GenerateUriParameters()` method and replace above code with the following:

```
Debug.Assert(parameterDescriptor == null);

if (apiParameter.Documentation == null && String.Equals(apiParameter.Name, "version", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
{
    apiParameter.Documentation = "Put description for version parameter here.";
}

// If parameterDescriptor is null, this is an undeclared route parameter which only occurs
// when source is FromUri. Ignored in request model and among resource parameters but listed
// as a simple string here.
ModelDescription modelDescription = modelGenerator.GetOrCreateModelDescription(typeof(string));
AddParameterDescription(apiModel, apiParameter, modelDescription);
```

This will give you:

[image]

Well, these approaches are not perfect (I'm not a fan of modifying generated `HelpPageConfigurationExtensions`). But seems like there is no other way to suppress or fill description for `version` parameter.